# Converting 8 bpp bitmap picture to 1 bpp?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, image-processing, aforge

Image manipulation is fun when it gets working. So far I am able to convert 24 bpp bitmap images to 8 bpp and do some tricks.

But I am stuck can't change them to 1 bpp which is exactly what I want. 
I work on .Net4 and I use an external library called Aforge.

does any body know how to convert an 8 bpp image to 1 bpp?

thanks

Answer (score 2):

Good question, introduced me to a great library :)
For solution:

`Bitmap binary = new Bitmap( 100, 100, PixelFormat.Format1bppIndexed );`

As found at:

http://www.aforgenet.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=1502

Answer (score 1):

You can use some image processing techniques such as Binarize and IntensityDetect to convert 8-bit images to black and white.
We searched the internet and found some commercial toolkits that support these functions, but they don't support many file formats. We finally found a toolkit named leadtools that supports these features with huge set of other images processing functions. I noticed that this toolkit can natively work with any bit depths.

Answer (score 0):

After a long search, I got this code example working.

[Bitonal (TIFF) Image Converter for .NET](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15186/Bitonal-TIFF-Image-Converter-for-NET)